# How to send script output to syslog

Tags: bash, syslog

I want to change a script which currently writes its output to logfile.

```
 ~/bin/setBatteryProtect.sh >> /tmp/battery.log
```

I want to have the output send to syslog. What is the best option to do so. The most reliable version seems to be to use `logger`. I actually would like to avoid to change the script - so I am looking for an option to send the complete output to syslog. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

`logger` reads from standard input if no message is specified on the command line and if `-f` isn't used (reads from file).

```
utility | logger
```

would log to syslog using logger, with one log entry per line of output from `utility`.

Add `-t tag` to add a tag to the log. Without it, the username of the user executing `logger` will be used as the tag.

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly well on the commandline but started from cron I get no entry in the syslog nor any other (visible) error. Do I need to consider other options when I use cron?

Comment: @MBushveld Hmm.. that's odd. I can not see why that would not work.

Comment: When I put this " /home/mi01/bin/setBatteryProtect.sh 2>&1 | logger -t setBattery" direct in crontab it works as expected. But when I put this in a file and place this in /etc/cron.daily/ then no autput is written. Since crontab kicks off anacron which loops thru the files and runs them I assume the issue somewhere there. Any hint how to get better info or even a solution?

Answer (score 0):

put this at the top of your script?  I found it in another site

exec 1> >(logger -s -t $(basename $0)) 2>&1

source: "https://www.urbanautomaton.com/blog/2014/09/09/redirecting-bash-script-output-to-syslog/"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.